# Ag Grid - Horizontal Scroll on ArrowRight/ArrowLeft

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I would like to make Ag-Grid scroll horizontally when the user presses Right/Left arrow keys.

First the user has to click inside the AG-Grid element and then press right or left arrow keys.

To do this, I have created a reference to the AG Grid scroll bar.

```
gridOptions.onGridReady = (event: GridReadyEvent) => {
      this.horizontalScrollbar = document.querySelector('div.ag-body-horizontal-scroll-viewport');
}
```

Then, I created this event

```
gridOptions.onCellKeyDown = (cellKeyDownEvent: CellKeyDownEvent) => {
      const kbEvent = cellKeyDownEvent.event as KeyboardEvent;
      if (kbEvent.key === 'ArrowRight') {
        this.horizontalScrollbar?.scrollBy(100, 0)
      } else if (kbEvent.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
        this.horizontalScrollbar?.scrollBy(-100, 0)
      }
}
```

This works normally. Now when the user clicks inside the AG Grid Table on columnA, then presses ArrowRight key, the AG grid scrolls horizontally to the right. But once columnA becomes partially or fully hidden, pressing ArrowRight key will cause the scroll to jump back to make columnA visible, creating a very weird scroll behavior.

Ag Grid seems to have some logic that forces the current view to show the last clicked cell.

How do I prevent AG Grid from automatically scrolling to the last clicked position? (columnA)